# Is it possible to fetch and parse email using mailutils+shell scripting only in Ubuntu server headless 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu, email, parsing

In my hoping to minimize the number of packages each needing their own configurations, I'm wondering if there is a way for me to retrieve email for parsing by script without installing any more email packages.  This is a remote-location system, dedicated to surveillance and has a standalone firewall, both boxes Ubuntu server headless 15.10.  I have mailutils installed and have a bash script that is successfully sending emails when needed with the 'mail' command, echo-piped.

mailutils comes with postfix, movemail, and readmsg which I am hoping I can use to read email from the email account that the ISP offers to me, which I have no other use for and have never retreived any email from it by any means. Along with that account and password, the ISP tells me their email servers are pop3.walnutel.net and smtp.walnutel.net, port in=110, port out=587.  To see if imap is available from them, I ping'd to imap.walnutel.net and discovered it does exist and has the same IP address as the other two email servers.  That is about all I know about the email account itself.

When I say "remote location", I simply mean 50 miles away from where I normally am and on a different ISP.  The emailing I envision will be me sending an email from my gmail account to the walnutel.net account when the firewall blacklists me wherever I'm at, then the email gets read and parsed by my firewall scripting to take that IP address off the blacklist.  I've made my firewall blacklist fairly aggressively, getting triggered to do so by any packet whatsoever trying any port whatsoever.  The only way a person can keep from getting blacklisted is to port knock properly before 2 minutes expires from their first knock.  The 2 minute delay only is allowed if their first port probed is also the first port of the port knocking sequence.  Therefore, I foresee a real possiblity I could inadvertently get myself blacklisted.  Until I get the answer for this posted question - and the script developed - I'm having my port-knockd daemon-triggered script also remove any blacklist entry existing for the IP address that passed the knock test.  Although highly secure as just described, I'm hoping to impress a prospective customer of this system with the final touch for internet security that this emailing configuration could provide.

In my research, I see others using additionally installed packages like dovecot, fetchmail, procmail, mutt, etc. for their retrieval and parsing.  I'm trying to avoid installing those or any other additional packages.  I find too few, if any, examples using just the utilities included in mailutils: postfix, movemail, readmsg.  Can anyone steer me to how-tos of email retrieval for parsing with no more mail-retrieval packages than mailutils and shell or python scripting?

Edit 12/25/15: I have learned that the email methodology I seek is called "bash sockets".  Unclear to me yet in my research is whether I'll for sure need to authenticate with my local email account credentials in order to send email reliably to my non-local gmail account, and whether I'll be required to use SSL (TLS, etc).  If required to use SSL/TLS to communicate with email servers, I fear I'll be VERY hard-pressed to find bash scripting examples of that.

Comment: This is a (slightly) improved version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412947/can-mailutils-alone-without-alpine-mutt-or-fetchmail-but-bash-ok-read-email which is currently on hold.

Comment: As commented earlier, Postfix is completely unrelated to mailutils. They do require *some* MTA for some of the functionality, and so to satisfy that dependency, your package manager will install the Postfix package as well.

Comment: I'll keep a lookout for a way. In the meantime, I'm tempted to wait and see if any IP can get past the first or second ports of the port knocking sequence, and if so, maybe install one or more of the packages I mentioned and do it that way. I'll admit that my port knocking whitelisting script sends me an email anyway if it also finds the IP address in the blacklist. Plus, the blacklist is located below the whitelist in the iptables INPUT chain rules, meaning any whitelist entry trumps an identical blacklist one, preventing a total 'blackout'. (knockd sees even blacklisted IPs)

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for clarifying that postfix is not part of mailutils.  It _seemed_ to get installed when I installed mailutils, maybe as a dependency, hence my presumption.

Comment: Erm; Bash is a thing and sockets are a thing and Bash has some support for sockets, but "Bash sockets" isn't a thing, and certainly not an "email methodology".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [GNU Mailutils Manual](http://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html#SEC1), all of the tools in the suite have both POP and IMAP support, so you should not need to install a separate tool for that. For your limited use case, it sounds like even POP could be adequate, although most grown-ups in this century would probably use IMAP for everything.

Several of the mailutils tools could support your plan -- a Sieve script could do more, while `readmsg` would require the calling script to perform the non-mail parts. If you are good with Bash and not particularly eager to learn Sieve, maybe go with `readmsg`?

On the other hand, if you go with Python, you don't even need `mailutils` - [`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) is part of the standard library since way back. (There is a [POP library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html), too.)

Comment: Thank you two. I'll keep a lookout for a way.  In the meantime, I'm tempted to wait and see if any IP can get past the first or second ports of the port knocking sequence, and if so, maybe install one or more of the packages I mentioned and do it that way. I'll admit that my port knocking whitelisting script sends me an email anyway if it also finds the IP address in the blacklist. Plus, the blacklist is located below the whitelist in the iptables INPUT chain rules, meaning any whitelist entry trumps an identical blacklist one, preventing a total 'blackout'. (knockd sees even blacklisted IPs)